# Reactjs/SemanticUi add if condition in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui

What I want is add `if` condition inside `map` function, but no success:

```
const CityOptions = Data.CityData.map((state, index) => ({
    key: index,
    text: state.name,
    value: state.id,
}));

render(){
return(
<Dropdown
   id="City"
   search selection
   options={CityOptions}
></Dropdown>
}
}
```

I tried:

```
 <Dropdown
     id="City"
     search selection
 >
     {Data.CityData.map((v,i) => {
         if(v.pid === this.state.cityValue){
             return (
                 <option key={i} value={v.id}>{v.name}</option>
             )
         }
         return true
     })}
 </Dropdown>
```

**Error:**

> React.Children.only expected to receive a single React element child.

And Also:

```
<Dropdown
   id="City"
   search selection
   options={CityOptions.pid === this.state.cityValue ? CityOptions : null}
/>
```

Result:

> No data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could `filter` first

```
Data.CityData.filter(x => x.pid === this.state.cityValue).map((v,i)  =>{
    return <option key={i} value={v.id}>{v.name}</option>
})
```

According with [Semantic UI's docs](https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown/) `options` is an `array` of `objects` following the pattern `{ text: '', value: '' }`, so you need to pass it like

```
const CityOptions = Data.CityData.filter(x => x.pid === this.state.cityValue).map((v,i)  =>{
    return{
        key: v.id,
        value: v.id,
        text: v.text
    }
})
```

Comment: Okay, it works but look like we are not in the right way of semantic ui, it add option ugly, I think semantic ui not accept adding html tag `<option/>`

Comment: See sample: `<div role="listbox" class="visible menu transition"><option value="2">cc</option><option value="3">ss</option></div>` here is output html

Comment: I'm not understanding, what are the problem now? Could you please elaborate better?

Comment: Sorry for bad english, yes I try: your code working good, but it add `<option/>` inside `<div` not `select` , I think semantic-ui in reactjs convert `<select>` to `<div>` because we add option after state changed. hope you understand my mean.

Comment: Let me see if I understood correctly. The `options` rendered by my code are beeing wrapped in a `div` instead of `select` ?

Comment: Yes. it because Semantic-UI turn it into div, and by your code we add <option> to <div> after state changed, your code's logic is right but not the right way for semanti ui

Comment: This one looks good, but something is wrong, I got error: Syntax error: Unexpected token (50:23)

Comment: Why? but the problem not solved yet, I mentioned in my question, it should work in semantic ui

Comment: Wrong question. my bad

Comment: Hmmm. Maybe the `key` property?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199707/discussion-between-dupocas-and-tour-travel).

Comment: Glad you're problem is solved. But... my code is exactly like this `text: v.text`, what changed?

Comment: No it is not, I already see `text: : v.text` two `:` in your code, also v.name, not v.text. After all, thanks for your help

Comment: hahahahahahaahaha My bad man. I've checked one hundred times and didn't notice. Glad you solved.